# Why is the committed memory reported by PSAPI smaller than the used physical memory?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, psapi

This question concerns the [PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684824(v=vs.85).aspx) struct from the Process Status API (PSAPI) on Windows.

From the documentation, I would assume that CommitTotal >= (PhysicalTotal - PhysicalAvailable) since CommitTotal also includes the page file in addition to physical memory.

However, on my system I get the following values that violate the assumption:

- CommitTotal = 7,943,270,400 (~ 7.4 GB)
- PhysicalTotal – PhysicalAvailable = 9,685,630,976 (~ 9 GB)

Comment: Not every RAM page needs to be backed by the paging file.  Examples are executable code, memory-mapped files and the biggest chunk, the file system cache.

Comment: I see. So to get the size of the pagefile, I can compute CommitLimit-PhysicalTotal. Is there also a way to compute how much of the page file is currently used?